# Using Unions in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm trying to use a Union in a Windows Forms application in C++. My code goes like this:

```
union mytypes1_t {
    unsigned long mylong;
    char mychar;
} mytypes1;
```

After the includes at the top of my Form1.h file, and:

```
for (int num = 0;num<3;num++) {
mytypes1.mychar[0]='a';
}
```

When a button is clicked.

I get the error ... "subscript requires array or pointer type"

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `mychar` is not an array. Did you want to do this: `mytypes1.mychar='a'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mychar is not an array or pointer you could instead declare it like so:

```
union mytypes1_t {
    unsigned long mylong;
    char mychar[4]; 
} mytypes1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that!

Answer (score 0):

`char mychar;` is not an **array** nor **pointer** type.

```
for (int num = 0;num<3;num++) { mytypes1.mychar[0]='a'; }
                                               ^^^
```

and the loop makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, like the error says, you can only use subscript `[]` with an array or a pointer type.

`mytypes1.mychar` is of type `char`  - That is not an array, nor is it a pointer.

An array would be something like this:  `char mychar[12];`

A pointer would be something like this:  `char* mychar;`  - but if you use the pointer, be sure to make it point to something first (such as a heap-allocated array).

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is a single character. When we do `char*` or `char[]` it allows us to store multiple chars on the the computer. This also means, you cannot access non-pointer chars like an array as you attempted to do (since arrays are essentially convient form of pointers when it comes to storing stuff).

You can change your code to the following:

```
union mytypes1_t {
    unsigned long mylong;
    char *mychar;
} mytypes1;
```